# IOS App crashes when attachement file is opened while uithread is busy

Tags: objective-c, ios, email-attachments

I have an app in which I have to do a lot of activity in `UIThread`. When `UIThread` is blocked and if I try to open an email attachment in my app, it crashes. I cannot get any crash log. The app quits. If I try to open when app is not busy then there is no problem. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @joe The main thread in IOS application.

Comment: @gladiator2345 I believe Joe's point is there is no such thing as UIThread. Perhaps you mean NSThread?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. What i meant was main thread of a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

The system is killing your application, it must be responsive, move your tasks to background thread and never block `UIThread`.

Use one of the following approaches:

1. `dispatch_async(...`
2. `[self performSelectorInBackgroundThread...`
3. `NSOperation/NSOperationQueue`

Comment: but I want to do UI Operations. Is it recommended to update uikit elements from another thread?

Comment: Opening email attachement should be done in bg thread, then presented to UI in main thread. Please paste some code so I can see what you are trying to do.